# is there anyway to pack some table rows together in html

Tags: html, html-table

i have a code like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ....
    </tr>
</table>
```

and i want to pack some of them together of it. maybe something like this:

```
<table>

  /* an Element to contain them */ 
    <tr>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ....
    </tr>
  /* end of the element */ 

  /* an Element to contain them */ 
    <tr>
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ....
    </tr>
  /* end of the element */ 

</table>
```

i have tried using DIV but it didn't worked

Comment: Please explain why do you want to pack rows together. Then it will be easier to help you.

Comment: The specification might help with what can be in what here https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table can have more than one `tbody` element. Wrap each set in its own [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody).

Comment: that is a good idea, it won't make any problem right?

Comment: or is it posible to have a ```<tbody>``` inside another one?

Answer (score 0):

You can group multiple `tr`s using `tbody` as follows.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody id="group1">
    <tr>
      <td>Group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Group 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="group2">
    <tr>
      <td>Group 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Group 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can i have a ```<tbody>``` in another?

Comment: What do you mean `in another`? Outside of `table` tag you mean?